# Resize classic header image to browser width [twitter bootstrap]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to twitter bootstrap, I think everything is set up correctly and I am trying to make the site responsive. The first thing I want to do is have my header jpeg image to be resized depending on the browser width. Can somebody give a fist hint?

Now I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="header-image.jpg">
</div>
```

The other divs with class container are resized properly, and I also already tried to fluid option.

Thank you,
Kasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `img-responsive` class on the image..

http://www.bootply.com/7R0qNWk74z

If you're looking for a full-width solution use a `row` inside a `container-fluid`..

http://www.bootply.com/Cc0rdXsJXP

Comment: Both links don't seem to work, in CSS I have added this: img {
     display: block;
     height: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: Bootply was temporarily down.. back up now